# Convert String to a JMS BytesMessage in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a String to a JMS BytesMessage.  Is there a good way to do this?

I need to do this because I have a method that takes in a String that is decrypted and I need to convert it into a BytesMessage in order to decrypt the message.

Thanks

Comment: What do you wanna know exactly? How to create a BytesMessage?

Comment: Have you tried `String.getBytes(Charset)` ?

Comment: Well I want to take a String that I already have and convert that into a BytesMessage.  I am not too familiar with BytesMessage as I am making changes to already existing code, so is this the wrong way to go about doing this?  And yes, I have done that, I can get the String to a bytes[] array but is there a way to convert that into a BytesMessage?

Comment: If the goal is to encrypt your message, why don't you use the built-in capability of your JMS provider?

Answer (score 2):

```
 byte[] bArray = "foo".getBytes("UTF-8");
 BytesMessage msg = session.createBytesMessage(); // throws JMSException
 msg.writeBytes(bArray);
```

Of course, like Arcadien said, you need to execute the code in an appropriate environment to obtain the javax.jms.Session object from.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late,
but better late than never.

The @Carlo answer is essentially correct,
except that you must catch an exception if you use `getBytes`
with a `String` parameter.

Here is a variation (of the getBytes call) that will not throw an exception:

```
final byte[] byteArray = "blammy".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final BytesMessage bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();

bytesMessage.writeBytes(byteArray);
```

The `StandardCharsets` class defines charsets that are guaranteed to be available on every implementation of the Java platform.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
byte[] String#getBytes()
```

to get a byte array from a string and write it to a ByteMessage

Comment: BytesMessage is an interface, not a class. You have to find a factory or an implementation of it in JMS to use it ; though I don't enough know it to give you roasted solution.